# Specify type *and* interface(s) of function parameter

Tags: c#, types, interface, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I have a structure of classes that I'd like to apply some odd constraints to:

```
public abstract class TopClass {}

public class ClassA : Topclass {}
public class ClassB : Topclass {}
public class ClassC : Topclass {}
public class ClassD : Topclass {}
public class ClassE : Topclass {}
```

I'd like to group these into categories, some of which overlap, so I can require this combination or that when using `TopClass`.  Since C# doesn't support multiple inheritances, I've been trying to use interfaces:

```
public abstract class TopClass {}

public interface IGroupA {}
public interface IGroupB {}

public class ClassA : Topclass, IGroupA          {}
public class ClassB : Topclass, IGroupA          {}
public class ClassC : Topclass, IGroupA, IGroupB {}
public class ClassD : Topclass, IGroupB          {}
public class ClassE : Topclass, IGroupB          {}
```

This all works fine, but actually *using* this craziness is where I run into trouble.  **I can't figure out how to specify that a parameter for a function should be of type `TopClass` and implement interface `IGroupA`**.  IE, I would like to be able to target classes `ClassA`, `ClassB`, and `ClassC` without explicitly naming them (so that a developer in charge of `TopClass` and it's decedents could easily redefine the groups without interfering with other developers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [*generic constraints*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) and you can specify both a *class* that the type should derive from and *interface(s)* that type should implement:

```
void MyFunction<T>(T argument) where T : TopClass, IGroupA
{

}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I had seen this format used in other questions, but I guess I mistook it for "`T` can be `TopClass` **or** `IGroupA`".  Thanks!

Comment: @SandyGifford if you see generics and constraints for the first time, I would recommend you to read some tutorials and look into documentations on msdn. and, if you have different questions don't edit your current question, instead [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).